# Shell script.....if error do this instead

Tags: shell, error-handling

At my home I have 2 PCs, my main windows gaming rig, and an ubuntu 13.04 file server. (NOT running ubuntu server just plain ubuntu)

I have the OS drive encrypted with luks (through installation)

But i have 5 Truecrypt ecrypted HDDs. They need to stay truecrypt for my needs. I have the following 2 scripts setup to mount my drives on boot of the PC.

This simple one to open terminal and run the next script-

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 10

gnome-terminal -e /home/kun7/.TrueCrypt/mount_truecrypt_volumes.sh
```

And then the following code runs to get truecrypt password and mount drive to my specified points (needs to goto specified points for my other programs/libraries/shortcuts etc

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter password ..."

oldConfig=`stty -g`
stty -echo
read password
stty $oldConfig

echo "Opening Pandora's Box ..."


truecrypt -t /dev/sdb5 /media/P --password="$password"  -k "" --protect-hidden=no
truecrypt -t /dev/sda1 /media/B --password="$password"  -k "" --protect-hidden=no
truecrypt -t /dev/sdd1 /media/M --password="$password"  -k "" --protect-hidden=no
truecrypt -t /dev/sde1 /media/V --password="$password"  -k "" --protect-hidden=no
truecrypt -t /dev/sdf /media/S --password="$password"  -k "" --protect-hidden=no

echo "Drives mounted ... Close when ready"

exit 0
```

This works great for what I need. On occasion. My problem is that I have 2 drives connected via a PCI card. NORMALLY they are detected by the OS as sdb5 and sda1, but every now and then they get identified as sdc5 and sdd1.

This causes my script return...

```
Enter password ...
Opening Pandora's Box ...
Enter your user password or administrator password: 
Error: No such file or directory:
/dev/sdb5
Incorrect password or not a TrueCrypt volume.

Enter password for /dev/sda1: Error: No such file or directory:
/dev/sdd1
Incorrect password or not a TrueCrypt volume.

Enter password for /dev/sdf:
```

What I'm wanting to do is to add an "if error" command at the end of my script to tell it. "If error, use this instead" and then list the alternate mount paths when the OS changes the drive points.

I think that makes sense.

Comment: Could i use the - if [ $? = 0 ]; then - command?and insert the new mount point there?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use the drives UUIDs instead.
You can get the drives UUID with:

```
 $ sudo /sbin/blkid /dev/sda1
 > /dev/sda1: UUID=<SOME-UUID-STRING> TYPE=<TYPE>
```

And with `blkid -U <UUID>` you query the device path. So in your script use this instead:

```
truecrypt -t $(/sbin/blkid -U <SOME-UUID-STRING>) /media/...
```

If you really prefer the "on error" approach:

```
function mount-truecrypt () {
    local dev=$1
    local mnt=$2
    local alternative_dev=$3
    truecrypt -t $dev $mnt --password="$password"  -k "" --protect-hidden=no || \
      truecrypt -t $alternative_dev $mnt --password="$password"  -k "" --protect-hidden=no
}
mount-truecrypt /dev/sdb5 /media/P /dev/sdc5
```

---

Update:

Ok, UUIDs don't work because the partition table isn't available before decrypting with `truecrypt` and the devices are kind of random.

Here some tips for your udev rules: [Writing udev rules](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) might help you and this command:

```
sudo udevadm info -a -p $(sudo udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sda)
```

(From [udevinfo](http://fredericiana.com/2010/05/28/udevinfo-on-ubuntu-10-4-lucid/)) Gives you all the udev infos on your drives.

Though that's probably not easy either, since the partitions won't be available to udev either ..
But you could figure out where the main block device of you drive is by creating a symlink for the drive with a rule like this:

```
ATTRS{model}=="<MODEL>", ATTRS{serial}=="<SERIAL>", ACTION=="add", SYMLINK+="<my-symlink>"
```

Then /dev/ points to the device (/dev/sda or so) with `readlink` you can follow links like this:

```
readlink -f /dev/<my-symlink>
```

So you could try this in your script:

```
truecrypt "$(readlink -f /dev/<my-symlink>)1" <args>
```

To mount partition 1 on that drive. I'm not sure if it works, but mighht give you some ideas .

Comment: It actually never occured to me to use the drive id`s at all......went a bit stupid and ended up googleblind......Cheers for those, i`ll give them a try

Comment: Im sorry to say that, i cant use the blkid approach.....tried it, and from what i can see, the problem seems to be that the UUID is assigned to the mounted crypted hard drive. So the blkid command only works once the drive is already mounted.....but im gonna have a go at your other approach. Just need to gather both sets of dev`s

Comment: Could i set the commands on 1 line and then insert an IF/ELSE command, then the second set?

That way it should work by running EITHER the first set of dev`s or the second and keep my links/librarys all working

Comment: Not sure I understand you, but you can also just do an  `if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ; then ... else ... fi` to check if the last command was successful.

Comment: Yeah thats what im thinking, currently when the PC loads up with the alternate dev`s some correspond to the script and some dont, so i need it to run either one OR the other. But as your 2 options dont work, im now thinking if i put the 5 truecrypt lines as 1 command with the "&&" i can put them into an IF?ELSE script. but i dont know exactly how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Ive tried all of the options, and a few more, but they dont work for my setup. Because of the PCI card, the HDDs change their /dev/... points randomly, so i cant rely on them being the same everytime i start up the PC. Im trying to figure out udev rules but im stumped. Is there any way to use `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/` instead of UUID in the truecrypt script? Im thinking if i can get the truecrypt script to find the HDDs model number,serial, or device path instead, i dont need to worry about the /dev/ or UUID

Comment: Yes, I believe they should be constant. Try using the `/dev/disk/by-id/` path for your drives. If they are available before mounting... I don't know how truecrypt works. The command `sudo hdparm -i /dev/sda1` might help you.

Comment: With truecrypt UUID doesnt work coz its from the partition, but with truecrypt there is no partition until its mounted. With `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id` and with `by-path` i get the full results without the drives mounted. So im trying 2 approaches ATM, custom udev rules (which i cant get working) to persistently set the /dev/sd**. And im thinking if i can get the truecrypt script to find the drives by their id or kernel path, that could work. Just gotta figure out the best way to go about it

Comment: AHA!!!! i am a genius.....well.....a persistent fool. But i think i got it working. I used `truecrypt -t /dev/disk/by-id/***link to truecrypt partition*** /media/P --password="$password"  -k "" --protect-hidden=no` and it seems to be working. Now to double check my script and reboot the pc.

Comment: Nope, im not! Turns out those links change if and when they want. Looks like my only option is going to be figuring out how to set custom udev rules to force the drives into specific /dev/sd**

Comment: I see, added some ideas on how to use udev rules for that ... good luck.

Comment: Cheers, currently playing around with different ATTRS. got my rules setup as `ACTION=="add" ,KERNEL=="ata1" ,ATTRS{model}==********* ,SYMLINK+="sdf%n"` setting them as f,g,h,i,j, so i know if they're working or not. If i manage to get them working, i`ll post for others to see

Comment: i am safe putting all 6 rules in the same file arn't I? all on different lines obviously

Comment: Yes, same file is ok. Are you sure the KERNEL attr is the same for usb and pci? Just model might not be enough, if your drives are the same one.

Comment: Well ive sat here for 3 days messing with many things, currently, im trying `ACTION=="add", ATTRS{model}=="ST98823AS       ", SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi", SYMLINK:="sda[0-9]*"` and im saving in `/etc/udev.ruls.d` tried saving as `00-******` and `70-******` but no success. I got a feeling this is gonna be a long arduous journey of trial and error

Comment: 1. Leave subsystems out, model and serial should be enough to id your drives. 2. use other symlinkes (none the system uses), just something like "mydrive-1". You can afterwards figure out where that link points to. That's easier than interfering with ubuntus udev rules. The name should then also be completely unimportant.

Comment: Touch wood, kiss the cat, fingers crossed, and all hail lord cthulu...i think i may have it working. I found a few tutorials by searching `persistent static drive udev` pointed me to a few pages, on from semantec - `Setting Persistent SCSI Device Names On Linux Using UDEV` turns out i was serching for the wrong thing. Yet again googlefoo prooves awesome, but just a case of language use to get the required result.

Comment: Its done.....OMG im so happy for that. I wrote a lil guise for what i did, and uploaded it to pastebin. Incase other people want to know what to do.....[http://pastebin.com/TnG9eQqQ] Thanks for your help mate. Putting me on the right path

Comment: That's great! You can post that as answer and accept it. The next poor soul dealing with this will then have a working answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that for terminal/script mounting of drives through truecrypt your doing this:

truecrypt -t /dev/sda /media/Stuff

But if the /dev/sda change for each physical drive everytime you boot up, then this makes the script worthless. All links, and libraries are setup from /media/stuff which in turn rely on /dev/sda pointing to the same drive each time. So i need to make some persistent /dev/*** points for truecrypt to use.

TIP: use udev to fond the info your using for matches, and make sure your setting completely random/customized /dev/***

```
Here is my current process for getting everything to work

1 - PC boots and takes rules from 10-custom-hdd-scsi.rules
2 - Login to Ubuntu where 1 script open terminal and then runs "3"
3 - Truecrypt script prompts for password, and mounts drives to specified mount points allowing for links/libraries to work.
```

First run - sudo /lib/udev/scsi_id --page=0x83 --whitelisted --device=/dev/sda and copy the result down. Do it for each drive you have, and you`ll have the Drives scsi id

**10-custom-hdd-scsi.rules - This file has been saved in /etc/udev/rules.d**

```
# These are the rules to force all drives into specific /dev/sd** slots for truecrypt mounting
#
#KERNELS - looks upwards in device path to find
#PROGRAM - Runs this. It is a serch for WWID (world wide ID)
#RESULT  - This is the result its looking for. It is the specific Drives ID
#SYMLINK - Create the following link (i.e. personal /dev/***)
#
# "==" means match this
# "+=" means if it exists, do this aswell
#
KERNEL=="sd*", PROGRAM=="/lib/udev/scsi_id --page=0x83 --whitelisted --device=/dev/%k", RESULT=="<DRIVES ID>", SYMLINK+="TC-a%n"

KERNEL=="sd*", PROGRAM=="/lib/udev/scsi_id --page=0x83 --whitelisted --device=/dev/%k", RESULT=="<DRIVES ID>", SYMLINK+="TC-b%n"

KERNEL=="sd*", PROGRAM=="/lib/udev/scsi_id --page=0x83 --whitelisted --device=/dev/%k", RESULT=="<DRIVES ID>", SYMLINK+="TC-c%n"

KERNEL=="sd*", PROGRAM=="/lib/udev/scsi_id --page=0x83 --whitelisted --device=/dev/%k", RESULT=="<DRIVES ID>", SYMLINK+="TC-d%n"

KERNEL=="sd*", PROGRAM=="/lib/udev/scsi_id --page=0x83 --whitelisted --device=/dev/%k", RESULT=="<DRIVES ID>", SYMLINK+="TC-e%n"
```

BANG - custom udev rules to create a link for each drive. so now you`ll have the standard /dev/sd** that change everytime, AND /dev/TC-a that will stay the same.

**First script to open terminal**

```
#!/bin/bash

gnome-terminal -e /home/kun7/.TrueCrypt/mount_truecrypt_volumes.sh
```

**And now the script telling truecrypt to mount your drives**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter password ..."

oldConfig=`stty -g`
stty -echo
read password
stty $oldConfig

echo "Opening Pandora's Box ..."


truecrypt -t /dev/TC-a /media/E --password="$password"  -k "" --protect-hidden=no
truecrypt -t /dev/TC-b /media/D --password="$password"  -k "" --protect-hidden=no
truecrypt -t /dev/TC-c /media/C --password="$password"  -k "" --protect-hidden=no
truecrypt -t /dev/TC-d /media/B --password="$password"  -k "" --protect-hidden=no
truecrypt -t /dev/TC-e /media/A --password="$password"  -k "" --protect-hidden=no

echo "Drives mounted ... Close when ready"

exit 0
```

-Now you'll boot up the PC, login, and get a terminal asking you for your truecrypt password.
-Type it in.

-And then you`ll be asked for your user password.

-The script will run, your drives will be mounted.

-And you now have continuous persistent mount point for your drives.